# How can I get the mentioned members from a Discord message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make custom commands and thus I am using the *on_message* event, but one issue I am having is getting the mentioned member in the message, so for example `;give @member`.

```
if message.content.lower().startswith(f";{command}") and message.raw_mentions and content == "None":
    mention = message.raw_mentions[0]
    if message.content.lower() == f";{command} {mention}":
        try:
            role = get(message.guild.roles, id=role)
            if role:
                member = message.guild.get_member(mention)
                if member:
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    await message.add_reaction("✅")
        except:
            return await message.channel.send("I do not have the permissions to give roles, If this is incorrect, You may need to move my role above the role you want to receive/give")
```

This what I currently have and I haven't been getting any errors, but I'm mainly having issues getting the member that is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the unnecessary steps to get the mention out of the message.

If you want to check if the entered message has user mentions, you can just check the attribute `message.mentions`. It returns an entire list of all Discord users that was mentioned in the message.

So you can write some code like this:

```py
if message.mentions:
```

as an example to check if users were mentioned in the message. And of course, you can get every mentioned user directly from the list with a small loop.

Aside from that, your method to get a role is really old. Instead, you should switch to the newer version of it to avoid bugs.

```py
# Check if users are mentioned
if message.mentions:
   # check if the role exists
   role = message.guild.get_role(int(role))
   if role is None:
      return

   # Add roles to all mentioned members
   for member in message.mentions:
       await member.add_roles(role)

   # Add an reaction after all roles was added
   await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

---

You should read these articles for more detailed documentation:

- *[message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mentions#discord.Message.mentions)*
- *[guild.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)*